# Changing pivot without transforming the geo

Tags: pivot, maya

is it possible to modify/grasp the selected object pivot point (transform, rotate and scale) in which the pivots are pointing towards the camera that user selected/ via a list of cameras in the scene?

I wanted to try out it manually before I try converting into coding but the following method that I tried, was unsuccessful:

1. create a locator
2. constrain the locator to aim in the way of the camera that I wanted it to point to
3. parent the geo to the locator
4. Freeze Transform on the geo and unparent it from the locator

While the method kinda work, in which is is pointing towards the camera, but the geo was rotated. I tried copying rotational values into the rotate axis, either the geo got rotates, or zero-ing out the rotational values, it is back to square one.

Any ideas?

Comment: do the freeze after unparenting?

Comment: @joojaa I tried it, however the axis will be defaulted back to the world axis

Comment: sorry, but whatever do you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry missing word changes the meaning. I meant to question,why you froze, was not a tip that freezing helps, but rather that freezing breaks the deal completely. My personal rule of thumb is never freeze anything as in ever for any reason. Too fundamental operation to be messing with.

Comment: @joojaa no worries, thought that it could a misspell wording going on. But are there any ways that I can get it to work, in which the attributes stayed as it it (if my obj was created at origin) without performing freeze transform?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i'd do it with python, if you want it coded.
This'll move your object's pivot without moving the object itself:

import maya.cmds as mc

mc.xform ('objectPivotYouWantToMove', piv=((mc.xform ('objectWhereYouWantPivotToBe', q=1, ws=1, piv=1))[0], (mc.xform ('objectWhereYouWantPivotToBe', q=1, ws=1, piv=1))[1], (mc.xform ('objectWhereYouWantPivotToBe', q=1, ws=1, piv=1))[2]))

What this does is moves the pivot of one object and puts it in the position of another's without moving the geo/shape.

If you want to move it without script select your object and then press the insert key. you can now move the pivot free of the object, if you hold down 'v' you can snap it to another.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for getting back to me. Though I have yet to try our your solution, I'm afraid that you may have got me wrong. Correct me if I am wrong, but instead of putting the pivot of objA and put it in the position of objB, I am trying to make objA pivot (still at the same position; center pivot of objA) to be the same as objB.